# Coloring line numbers in less?

Tags: colors, less

Please consider the following example:

```
$ grep --color=always -n 'Format\|Files' /usr/share/doc-base/doc-base | less -R
```

Here, `grep` will color also the line numbers of the matches, and `less` will display it.

I know I could show the entire file with line numbers in `less` with:

```
$ less -N /usr/share/doc-base/doc-base
```

My question is - is there a way, to get `less` to display the entire file with line numbers - but where the line numbers are colored (as in the case with the `grep` output)?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Well, found something related to the above example - just have `grep` additionally match "start of line" (`^`), and all non-matching lines will pass "unharmed", with only the line numbers colored:

```
$ grep --color=always -n 'Format\|Files\|^' /usr/share/doc-base/doc-base | less -R
```

... (and as a bonus, matches stay highlighted).

However, I'd still like to know if `less` can be persuaded to do this "natively"?